# In the early days of electricity did people think in terms of a big electric motor in the loft

Tags: electricity

I remember reading once that when electric motors first became available for household use, people thought that there would be one big motor in the loft, with drive belts feeding devices in different parts of the house.  Unfortunately, a search for information about this hasn't come up with anything.  Does anyone have more details of whether people actually thought this way, or did I just imagine it?

Comment: I think you are confusing domestic versus industrial power.  Factories in the 19th century commonly had a central power shaft with belts driving various power tools on on the floor.

Comment: @kimchilover  I think the question here is whether people expected home power systems to 'clone' industrial designs or not.

Comment: You might be right; maybe quantropy can clarify.  But homes typically did not have steam engines, so why would electrification imply features of steam-powered factories?

Comment: @kimchilover, probably because people had observed the retrofitting of electric motors in buildings that were designed for steam power, so the mechanical distribution of power from a central place remained using existing shafts and belts, but the steam-powered engine had been replaced by a large electric motor. Small electric motors local to each machine would have been costly, perhaps heavier on floors not designed to bear additional weight, and would have required the distribution of electrical power using cables (and control of it using newfangled switches).